# Apache spark using native dependencies - driver/executor code flow in standalone mode

Tags: java, opencv, apache-spark

I have setup spark in standalone mode (single node in my laptop), tried to integrate opencv to read a set of images from a directory and detect faces in each image. I am trying to understand how the native dependencies are shipped to executor jvm, I would have thought that in the given below program,  System.loadLibrary function would get executed as part of driver jvm, and the executor jvm would fail when the anonymous function tries to find the native library. But contrary to my understanding, the program works fine. Can someone explain how this works and what part of code is shipped from driver to executor.

```
 public static void main( String[] args )
 {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("spark://localhost:7077").setAppName("Image detect App");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier("/home/xx/Project/opencv-3.1.0/data/haarcascades_cuda/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");

    File tempDir = new File("/home/xx/images/new");
    String tempDirName = tempDir.getAbsolutePath();

    JavaPairRDD<String, PortableDataStream> readRDD = sc.binaryFiles(tempDirName,3);
    List<Tuple2<String, PortableDataStream>> result = readRDD.collect();
    for (Tuple2<String, PortableDataStream> res : result) 
    {
        Mat image = Imgcodecs
                .imread(res._1().replace("file:",""));

        MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);

        for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
            Imgproc.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
                    new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
        }
        String filename = res._1().replace("file:","") + "_out";
        Imgcodecs.imwrite(filename, image);
    }
```

}
                Have created a jar with the above program and ran the following spark submit command, it works fine as expected.

./bin/spark-submit --verbose --master spark://localhost:7077 --num-executors 2 --class com.xxx.MainSparkImage --jars /home/xx/Project/opencv-3.1.0/release/bin/opencv-310.jar --driver-library-path /home/xx/Project/opencv-3.1.0/release/lib /home/xx/ImageProcess.jar

Thanks
Srivatsan

Comment: spark.driver.extraClassPath 
spark.executor.extraClassPath  have you tried these  during spark submit?

Comment: Will try spark.executor.extraClassPath, going by its name, looks like that should be the one to ship the dependencies to the executor. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<Tuple2<String, PortableDataStream>> result = readRDD.collect();
```

This line would cause the RDD to be collected back to the driver as a local collection. The rest of the code (for loop) executes locally within the driver. Hence you don't see any errors related to missing native libraries on the executors.

Comment: Ooops...thanks for spotting it :-)...I will try not to use collect, instead use anonymous function. will check if I get an error this time

Comment: Yes, I could see the native dependency errors when they are referred within the anonymous function.  The link error is gone when the LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set to  /home/xx/Project/opencv-3.1.0/release/lib (in sbin/spark-config.sh),   Thanks for your help.
BTW tried setting  spark.executor.extraClassPath and spark.executor.extraLibraryPath, but they dont seem to resolve my link issue, I am not finding any good references on the usage of these two parameters w.r.t native dependencies.